# extracting patterns in an image

Tags: c#

I would like to extract 3 different types of patterns from an image. The patterns are top-open rectangle, rectangle and bottom-open rectangle as shown in the image. [image] Kindly suggest an approach.

Comment: learns lots of maths and computer science, springs to mind.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. What have you tried in solving this problem, do *you* have any ideas? If you present a solution but are having problems then people will help; rather than just asking for the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with aforge but I am finding it difficult to decide upon the pattern.

Comment: Edge Detection algorithms are good for this kind of pattern finding because lines are either vertical or horizontal. You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Answer (score 1):

Read RGB values of each pixel and convert it into 1 or 0 based on its RGB value then find the sort of patterns you required (something like below:)

```
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
11111111111111111111111111111111111111

11111111111111111111111111111111111111
11000000000000000000000000000000000011      
11000000000000000000000000000000000011 
11000000000000000000000000000000000011 
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
11111111111111111111111111111111111111

11111111111111111111111111111111111111
11000000000000000000000000000000000011      
11000000000000000000000000000000000011 
11000000000000000000000000000000000011 
11000000000000000000000000000000000011
```

Answer (score 0):

Load Image from file. Copy bitmap to new Image object with Transform (if required) and specify location on source / destination to copy. Save the new Image